# 1064 SQL You have an error in your SQL syntax; Python List to String Convert?

Tags: python, project

I'm still new to coding and sql, and I am working on a library management database system as a project.
And I keep getting a 1064 when trying to store my information in my database.
I'm pretty sure it's trying to tell me that the authors are Lists, and need to be a string, but I'm not sure how to do that, and if I can without query entries!

below is the def in question!

```
def googleAPI(self):

    lineTitle = str(titleInfo.text())
    # create getting started variables
    api = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:"
    isbn = lineTitle.strip()#input("Enter 10 digit ISBN: ").strip()

    # send a request and get a JSON response
    resp = urlopen(api + isbn)
    # parse JSON into Python as a dictionary
    book_data = json.load(resp)

    # create additional variables for easy querying
    volume_info = book_data["items"][0]["volumeInfo"]
    author = volume_info["authors"]
    # practice with conditional expressions!
    prettify_author = author if len(author) > 1 else author[0]

    # display title, author, page count, publication date
    # fstrings require Python 3.6 or higher
    # \n adds a new line for easier reading
    gTitle = str(volume_info['title'])
    pCount = str(volume_info['pageCount'])
    pubDate = str(volume_info['publishedDate'])
    author = str(volume_info["authors"])
    prettify_author = author if len(author) > 1 else author[0]
    stringAuthor = str(prettify_author)

    insertBooksF = "insert into "+bookTable+" values('"+isbn+"','"+gTitle+"','"+stringAuthor+"','"+pubDate+"','"+pCount+"')"
    try:
        cur.execute(insertBooksF)
        con.commit()
        print("You failed at failing")
    except:
        print("You actually failed")



    print(f"\nTitle: {volume_info['title']}")
    print(f"Author: {prettify_author}")
    print(f"Page Count: {volume_info['pageCount']}")
    print(f"Publication Date: {volume_info['publishedDate']}")
    print("\n***\n")
```

I believe this line is the one needed adjusting

```
 insertBooksF = "insert into "+bookTable+" values('"+isbn+"','"+gTitle+"','"+stringAuthor+"','"+pubDate+"','"+pCount+"')"
```

Comment: Your comparison is wrong.  If `author` is always a list, just do You want `prettify_author = author if isinstance(author,str) else  author[0]`.  And you should NEVER fill in your own fields like that; I'll show you the right way in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should ALWAYS let the database connector substitute your field values.  Otherwise, you open yourself up to SQL injection, where a malicious user provides a field value like `"; delete * from table;`

```
    stringAuthor = author if isinstance(author,str) else author[0]

    insertBooksF = "insert into "+bookTable+" values(?,?,?,?,?)"
    cur.execute(insertBooksF, (isbn, gTitle, stringAuthor, pubDate, pCount))
```

Comment: It turns out I needed to use %s instead of ? for the newer formatting it seems!